How can I fit content in visible page while using aspect-ratio?
I have a component on my page (named grid in the example).
I’d like this component to achieve the following constraints:

maintain 1:1 aspect ratio
be as big as possible
stay within the bounds of the viewport (no scrollbars)
ideally without JavaScript

I’ve been able to satisfy 1, 2, and 4, but not 3:

when the viewport is portrait-oriented (more height than width), the grid and its children will shrink as desired, to maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio.
when the viewport is landscape-oriented, the grid component expands beyond the bottom of the viewport, creating a scrollbar.

Here’s the HTML I’m looking at:
<div id="wholePage" class="black">
  <div>top bar placeholder</div>
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="row darkGray">
      <div class="column red"></div>
      <div class="column yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row lightGray">
      <div class="column green"></div>
      <div class="column blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And here’s the associated CSS:
#wholePage {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#grid {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.row {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


If your real life example is as simple as your given code you could just size it using vmin.

You can use aspect-ratio and max-width/height to keep it from going outside parent container (here <body>):


* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Needed here to prevent border making scrollbar */
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width 100%; /* Or any other size */
  height: 100%; /* Or any other size */
}

.box {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* This keeps it square */
  max-height: 100%; /* This sets largest side */
  border: 5px solid green;
}
<div class="box"></div>




what does box-sizing: border-box; do, and why does it need to be applied to everything?

this pretty much works, but is there a way to make it work without specifying an explicit percentage height for the placeholder div in my original example?

This solution doesn't constrain the box width on landscape viewports.

@BrettDonald Yes it does. The box size is as big as possible while maintaining an 1:1 aspect ratio, regardless of orientation.

Done some further testing and will clarify that on my Mac, it does indeed work in Chrome, but in Safari it does not.

@BrettDonald Good catch! Fixed that now. Commented further.

As per @AHaworth’s comment, the key here is width: 100vmin, and I would use a grid to implement the rows and columns.


body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body, .column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

.darkGray .column {
  background: #333;
}

.lightGray .column {
  background: silver;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  border: 2vw solid red;
}

.yellow {
  color: gold;
  border: 2vw solid gold;
}

.green {
  color: green;
  border: 2vw solid green;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  border: 2vw solid blue;
}
<div id="grid">
  <div class="row darkGray">
    <div class="column red">Red</div>
    <div class="column yellow">Yellow</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row lightGray">
    <div class="column green">Green</div>
    <div class="column blue">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.
